# Concatenate three columns data into one column with single column values also in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, string-concatenation

Can anyone tell me which command is used for concatenate three columns data into one column in PostgreSQL database?

e.g. If the columns are

```
begin | Month | Year
   12 |     1 | 1988
   13 |     3 | 
   14 |       | 2000
      |     5 | 2012
```

output:

```
Result
12-1-1988 
13-3-null
14-null-2000
null-5-2012
```

Actually, I have concatenated two columns but it is displaying only those values in the result
which is not null in all columns but i want to display that value also which is not null in single 
column.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply used a standard concatenation function like `concat()` or the `||` operator, you'd get a complete `null` string when any element is `null`.

You could use the function `concat_ws()` which ignores a `null` value. But you are expecting them to be shown.

So you need to cast the real `null` value into a non-null text `'null'`. This could be done using the `COALESCE()` function, which takes several arguments and returns the first non-null. But here the problem occurs, that the `'null'` string is of another type (`text`) than the columns (`int`). So you have to equalize the types, e.g. by casting the `int` values into `text` before. So, finally your query could look like this:

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2be67c3a4a75179176ecd932dac66d71)

```
SELECT
    concat_ws('-',
        COALESCE(begin::text, 'null'), 
        COALESCE(month::text, 'null'), 
        COALESCE(year::text, 'null')
    )
FROM mytable
```